# How to detect class of the element

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to make that if I click on some of SOME TEXT item in .leftcol, it makes red the .rightcol item that has the same **second category**.

But I need that in one unique function, so the second class should be detected with the code.

I can't figure out how to complete the script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.leftcol DETECT SECOND CLASS').click(function() {
    $('.rightcol DETECT SECOND CLASS').css('color', 'red');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="leftcol aerospace-defense">SOME TEXT</li>
<li class="leftcol business-enablement">SOME TEXT</li>
<li class="leftcol cardiology">SOME TEXT</li>
<li class="leftcol cell-biology">SOME TEXT</li>


<li class="rightcol aerospace-defense" style="color: red;">Aerospace & Defense</li>
<li class="rightcol business-enablement" style="color: red;">Business Enablement</li>
<li class="rightcol cardiology" style="color: red;">Cardiology</li>
<li class="rightcol cell-biology" style="color: red;">Cell Biology</li>
```

Comment: Make a bit more efforts in explaining your question please.

Comment: Ok so if I click on "SOME TEXT" that has class .leftcol.aerospace-defense it should make red the item that belongs to .rightcol.aerospace-defence class. What to add to "DETECT SECOND CLASS" in the function so that the system will recongnize the second class byhimself?

Comment: `.rightcol` elements already have `color` set to `"red"` at `style` attribute.

Comment: Yes but in this case ALL items in .rightcol will become red,  i need red only the item that has the same second class

Comment: What do you mean? The elements already have `color` set to `"red"`

Comment: I mean if i click on item that has class .leftcol.cardiology, it should make red the item that has class .rightcol.cardiology

Comment: Yes, though at `html` at Question the element already has `color` set to `"red"`. Should you remove `style` attributes at `.rightcol` elements that set `color` to `"red"` at the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few suggestions:

- The left and right list could be wrapped up in a parent `ul` with class `<ul class="leftcol">` and `<ul class="rightcol">`
- `click` event handler could be attached to left list item and the right list could be controlled as in the sample below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".leftcol li").click(function(event) {
    // Get the `class` of clicked element in the left-list
    var myClass = $(this).attr('class');

    // Default the right-list style 
    $(".rightcol li").css({
      "color": "red"
    });

    // Check if any list item on the right-side has the same class and action it based on that. 
    var rightColumnSelector = ".rightcol li." + myClass;
    $(rightColumnSelector).css({
      "color": "green"
    });

  });
});
```

```css
.leftcol,
.rightcol {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="leftcol">
  <li class="aerospace-defense">aerospace-defense</li>
  <li class="business-enablement">business-enablement</li>
  <li class="cardiology">cardiology</li>
  <li class="cell-biology">cell-biology</li>
</ul>

<ul class="rightcol">
  <li class="aerospace-defense" style="color: red;">Aerospace & Defense</li>
  <li class="business-enablement" style="color: red;">Business Enablement</li>
  <li class="cardiology" style="color: red;">Cardiology</li>
  <li class="cell-biology" style="color: red;">Cell Biology</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is here to catch the click events of any element with the `leftcol` class, and then read what the second class of that element is with the help of `$(this).attr("class").split(' ')[1]`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.leftcol').click(function() {
    var secondClass = $(this).attr("class").split(' ')[1]
    $('.rightcol.' + secondClass).css('color', 'blue');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="leftcol aerospace-defense">SOME TEXT</li>
<li class="leftcol business-enablement">SOME TEXT</li>
<li class="leftcol cardiology">SOME TEXT</li>
<li class="leftcol cell-biology">SOME TEXT</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li class="rightcol aerospace-defense" style="color: red;">Aerospace & Defense</li>
<li class="rightcol business-enablement" style="color: red;">Business Enablement</li>
<li class="rightcol cardiology" style="color: red;">Cardiology</li>
<li class="rightcol cell-biology" style="color: red;">Cell Biology</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute contains selector, `.split()`, `.pop()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.leftcol').click(function() {
    $('.rightcol[class*=' + this.className.split(" ").pop() + ']')
    .css('color', 'blue');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="leftcol aerospace-defense">SOME TEXT</li>
  <li class="leftcol business-enablement">SOME TEXT</li>
  <li class="leftcol cardiology">SOME TEXT</li>
  <li class="leftcol cell-biology">SOME TEXT</li>

</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="rightcol aerospace-defense" style="color: red;">Aerospace & Defense</li>
  <li class="rightcol business-enablement" style="color: red;">Business Enablement</li>
  <li class="rightcol cardiology" style="color: red;">Cardiology</li>
  <li class="rightcol cell-biology" style="color: red;">Cell Biology</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split` method on the class attribute

```
$('.leftcol').click(function()  {
   var secondClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
   $('.' + secondClass).css('color', 'red);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will find **every** instance of the second class of an element with class `.right` when an element with the class of `.left` and matching second class is clicked on. This function can apply to your HTML layout by changing the `.left` and `.right` classes respectively.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$(function() {
  $('.left').on('click', function(e) {
    var self = this;
    var cat = self.classList.item(1).toString();
    $('.right').each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass(cat)) {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='categories'>
  <caption>Categories</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Category</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='left astronomy'>DATA</td>
      <td class='right astronomy'>Astronomy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='left zoology'>DATA</td>
      <td class='right zoology'>Zoology</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='left psychology'>DATA</td>
      <td class='right psychology'>Psychology</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='left zoology'>DATA on Zoology</td>
      <td class='right astronomy'>Astronomy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='left astronomy'>DATA on Astronomy</td>
      <td class='right psychology'>Psychology</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='left psychology'>DATA on Psychology</td>
      <td class='right zoology'>Zoology</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```